# Why are there two "new Intent"? Will they make two different Intents?

Tags: java, android

For below codes, as you can see, one `new Intent` is in `bindService()`, and another `new Intent` occurs in `startService()`. And I just wonder if there will be two Intents finally? Or the two Intents are still OK?

```
bindService(new Intent(this, MusicPlayerService.class),
        mPlaybackConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
startService(new Intent(this, MusicPlayerService.class));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is equivalent to:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MusicPlayerService.class);
bindService(intent, mPlaybackConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
startService(intent);
```

In the code you provided, an identical `Intent` object is created each time.

The code is equivalent in the sense that they both do the same thing. However, using one Intent throughout would be very very slightly faster, as the object is only created once. Other than that, both are correct, and both do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think this code,

```
bindService(new Intent(this, MusicPlayerService.class),
        mPlaybackConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
startService(new Intent(this, MusicPlayerService.class));
```

is equivalent to,

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MusicPlayerService.class);
bindService(intent, mPlaybackConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
startService(intent);
```

In the first one, there are two distinct intents created. But in the second one, only a single intent is created, so better use the second code.